# Is it possible to extract the JSON metadata from a PBIX file?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Recent versions of Power BI Desktop have included a preview feature to "Store datasets using enhanced metadata format" which stores the model metadata in a JSON format. However, since the PBIX file is in a proprietary Zip format, you just can't open it and peek inside.

Is it possible to somehow extract this JSON model metadata from a PBIX and save it as a JSON file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the extension on a PBIX file to .zip and peek inside like a normal zip folder.

It looks something like this:

[image: PBIX Zip]

Most of these files can then be opened with a text editor.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but my Metadata file contains almost nothing. So, I'm guessing the actual data model metadata is contained in the DataModel file? However, this is in a binary format.

Comment: What particular kind of metadata are you looking for?

Comment: In order to get the decompressed (XPress9) DataModel JSON you should first export your PBIX to PBIT then rename that to .zip

Answer (score 2):

Do you Try to open Your PowerBI model in TabularEditor and save it to file?

https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Power-BI-Desktop-Integration

[image]

Then we have everything in a json format

Comment: yes, that would work and is a great answer. The only problem is that, at the moment, Tabular Editor is not, yet, an approved app I can put on my work laptop.

Comment: If I edit the json files this way - how can I turn them back into a .pbit file?